# org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression: fit, train, and predict

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Consider the following Spark MLlib code taken from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-classification-regression.html#linear-regression):

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression

// Load training data
val training = spark.read.format("libsvm")
  .load("data/mllib/sample_linear_regression_data.txt")

val lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setMaxIter(10)
  .setRegParam(0.3)
  .setElasticNetParam(0.8)

// Fit the model
val lrModel = lr.fit(training)

// Print the coefficients and intercept for linear regression
println(s"Coefficients: ${lrModel.coefficients} Intercept: ${lrModel.intercept}")

// Summarize the model over the training set and print out some metrics
val trainingSummary = lrModel.summary
println(s"numIterations: ${trainingSummary.totalIterations}")
println(s"objectiveHistory: [${trainingSummary.objectiveHistory.mkString(",")}]")
trainingSummary.residuals.show()
println(s"RMSE: ${trainingSummary.rootMeanSquaredError}")
println(s"r2: ${trainingSummary.r2}")
```

I see there is a fit method, which works similarly to train.  But I can find no predict method in the [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/regression/LinearRegression.html).

Is there supposed to be no predict function?  Now, I know I can make a prediction by taking the dot product of the coefficents of the model and the point I'm trying to make a prediction for and adding the model's intercept.

But is that what the library writers' expect people to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel@transform(dataset:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[_]):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame), which is part of almost all `ML` models. This receives a `DataFrame` with a column called `features.`

Comment: And "prediction" is the output column name?